# Open a webpage when first click on a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I need open a `webpage` when first click on a `TextBox` in form `c# ASP.NET 4`.

I think for resolve this problem use the `OnTextChanged` property in `TextBox` :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" CssClass="24" OnTextChanged="tb1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in *code-behind* I have added:

```
protected void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

But the redirect not working.

How to resolve this?

Comment: You are using the wrong event.  You need to use the onFocus event.  I can't remember how or if you can do this on the server side, but do a search for JavaScript and onFocus

Comment: Well, of course a `TextChanged` event isn't going to work for mouse clicks. I think you'll have to use Javascript for something like this; http://forums.asp.net/t/1085050.aspx?OnClick+Event+for+Text+Box+in+ASP+NET+with+C+  then you can just set a bool in the JS that determines if it's the "first click" or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnTextChanged` is a server side event . It would be better to use JavaScript for this purpose like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Open() {
        window.showModalDialog("http://www.google.com/");
    }
</script>
```

And to open webpage when `onclick` :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="Open();"></asp:TextBox>
```